# CSS animation not animating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I want to make a `menu slider` with `CSS animations`.

My animation works but it just shows the begin and end state without gradually animating it.

Check out my pen I made (CSS is little screwed up but bug/mistake is there): [click here for pen](http://codepen.io/G_4s/pen/Obwqge)

Appreciate all help.

Comment: Your pen link is a 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this.

```
@keyframes openmenu {
    0%   {width: 0%;}
    100% {width: 100%;}
}

@keyframes closemenu {
    0% {width: 100%; }
    100% {width: 0%;}
}
```

PEN: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xRJBJj

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't need fine control over the span of animation, you can use transition here as the animation is going to happen only between start and end point.

See the pen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qqyvxK)

Replace your classes with following styles:

```
.open-menu {
    max-width: 400px;
    max-height: 400px;
    transition: all 2s ease;
}

.close-menu {
    max-width: 0;
    max-height: 0;
    transition: all 2s ease;
}
```

Currently, we can only transition or animate between two fixed values, so it is the reason `auto` will not work.

So we usually set `max-height` and `max-width` to values which width and height will never reach.

Comment: thx for your answer but the original idea is little more complex this was a test with width only